# :not(:last-child) property not working (SCSS)

Tags: sass

I need to add `0` margin in the last child of the paragraph class. So I write:

```
.paragraph{
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    &:last-child{
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }   
};
```

And it's works fine but in order to make it more simple I write:

```
.paragraph{
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    &:not(:last-child){
        margin-bottom: 3rem;
    }  
};
```

Now it's not working. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/q36Lucjn/15/) is the `jsfiddle` code. Where I did wrong?

Comment: It works as you expect, but you have some errors in your SCSS (unnecessary semicolons, etc.). Look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/vcyrtq5a

Comment: It still not removing margin for the last child. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/jd54moy1/3/) I just edited your code and add a border. @EMiDU Eventually you add not to have `color:red` property for the last child which is also didn't work.

Comment: Paragraphs have default margin. Just set `margin:0` in order to remove it. I've added `color:red` for paragraphs which are not last childs (`&:not(:last-child)`) but every paragraph in [your code](https://jsfiddle.net/jd54moy1/3/) is last child, so nothing is red.